# want slider image size to be shown from left to right of the screen

Tags: html, css, image, size

I planned to use slider in my magento homepage. The slider should cover entirely from left to right. The image should cover entirely from left to right with the height of 500px in all size monitors.

Now i'm using the image size as 1600 px w & 500px ht. Initially it shows scroll bar in my bottom of the page. now i gave overflow:hidden. so it's showing ly half of the image...

I want the entire image should be shown in all dimension window. what is th image size should i use & give me some css hints,,,

Plz help me to achieve this....

Comment: You have not described your problem properly. Without the related CSS/HTML no one will be able to help you.

Comment: use property `position:relative;` for image container hope will do the work, Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Basically, it should fill the space of the parent horizontally and then constrain proportions as the width scales down. If you want it to stay at that height, simply replace `height:auto;` with `height:500px;`.

```
<style>
.container_img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<img class="container_img" src="http://www.wesleyeterry.com/startup.png">
```

Also, just to be clear, `container_img' can be replaced with any class name you come up with.